# Python Tkinter: Opening a picture "multiplatform"

Tags: python, image, tkinter, multiplatform

I'm working on a hangman project with my friend. The back-end part is finished, now we're working on the front-end part in Tk.

We want to open the image for the hangman. We want to upload it to our friends, so writing the file's location that is on our PC/pendrive isn't a good way, because if someone wants to try it on their computer, they can't, unless they edit the path.

We tried this, but it didn't work:

```
hangman = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="1.jpg")
```

So we need a command to open a file (ex. hangman/1.png) on any drive (ex. C:, E:)

Comment: Use [`tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename).

Comment: Thanks, we'll try it.

Comment: why can't you simply use relative paths? then ship your program in a folder or zip file that contains both the executable and the image file and then the executable would open that file using a relative path or use some of the `os` methods to get the full path by concatenation